# Express Gateway

Tags: express, express-gateway

I'm new to node js, I having a issue with express-gateway 
I have installed node(V 10.0.0), express(V 4.16.3) & express-gateway.

I'm getting an error:
D:\User\Test\Express-Gateway>eg -version
'eg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

as I fire cmd: eg -version or eg express-gateway create

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed Express Gateway globally by doing `nom i -g express-gateway`?

Comment: @Vincenzo Yes , I did

Comment: This is interesting. Unfortunately I do not have a Windows machine to replicate it but I'd struggle to see what's the problem. Are you receiving any error during the global installation?

Comment: Are you using cmd or powershell? If you're using cmd, I'd recommend re-doing the install using powershell and then see if you can access it that way.

Comment: @Vincenzo, No I'm able to install express gateway successfully.

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn, I tried the same using power shell, but it didin't work.

Comment: I do not really know what to say. Are you still facing such issue? Is it replicable somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In case of a valid installation, you can find a corresponding windows command script (named eg) residing in your node installation folder (e.g.: C:\Program Files\nodejs\eg). 
Next the windows environment variable PATH has to contain the above mentioned path (in order to check this just run PATH in cmd shell => this will print out the value of PATH, which is a list of file paths seperated by semi colons). If the node.js entry is missing, you can add the path by updating the variable manually.